# Custom Youtube angular directive not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, youtube

I am trying to use the [Angular Youtube Embed](https://github.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed). I have stored the youtube video IDs in my db and trying to call it as shown below

```
<div class="row" ng-show="videos.length > 0">
            <div class="col-md-4 img-portfolio" ng-repeat="data in videos">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                        <youtube-video video-id="{data.videoYTID}}"></youtube-video>                
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="portfolio-item.html">{{data.videoTitle}}</a>
                </h3>
                <p>{{data.videoYTID}}</p>
                <p>{{data.category}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and my app.js goes as this

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, services) {
services.getVideos().then(function(data){
    $scope.videos = data.data;

});
});
```

You can see what access the  [Angular Youtube Embed JS here.](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brandly/angular-youtube-embed/master/src/angular-youtube-embed.js)

But it does not seem to work. It is just showing the objects as shown below.

[image: Youtube Directive - Angular]

When I try normally by passing a id straight to the `$scope` variable it is working. Like below

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, services) {
services.getVideos().then(function(data){
    $scope.videos = data.data;
    $scope.videos2  = 'smSrt93dtf'  
});
});


<div class="row" ng-show="videos.length > 0">
                <div class="col-md-4 img-portfolio" ng-repeat="data in videos">
                    <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                            <youtube-video video-id="smSrt93dtf"></youtube-video>                
                    </a>
                    <h3>
                        <a href="portfolio-item.html">{{data.videoTitle}}</a>
                    </h3>
                    <p>{{data.videoYTID}}</p>
                    <p>{{data.category}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Update**

[image: Only error in console]

JSON DATA :

```
[{"videoNumber":"170","videoTitle":"Venkateshwaran Selvaraj","videoYTID":"sMKoNBRZM1M","category":"22 Nothing"},{"videoNumber":"168","videoTitle":"American Souvenirs","videoYTID":"sMKoNBRZM1M","category":"149 Spinnaker Dr."},{"videoNumber":"167","videoTitle":"Herkku Gifts","videoYTID":"sMKoNBRZM1M","category":"Brehmen St. 121"}]
```

I am a beginner of angularjs. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: R u missing { in {data.videoYTID}}

Comment: No. That is my mistake while pasting it on SO.

Comment: There must be some error in console, what does it say?

Comment: Have u injected youtube like this... angular.module('myApp', ['youtube-embed']);

Comment: I have updated the question with the console error.

Comment: @Reena Yes I have. Along with another dependency - var app = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute','youtube-embed'
]);

Comment: Can you paste the data/json that you get here : $scope.videos = data.data;? Are you able to get the data from the service?

Comment: Don't use brackets({{}}) when you use variable in attribute: video-id="data.videoYTID"

Comment: Oh Gosh!. I thought I tried that. Anyways. It worked. Both video-id=data.videoYTID and video-id="data.videoYTID" worked.